# Why can not we use prometheus as billing system?

Tags: billing, prometheus

I want to know why prometheus is not suitable for billing system.
the Prometheus overview page says 

`If you need 100% accuracy, such as for per-request billing, Prometheus is not a good choice as the collected data will likely not be detailed and complete enough.`

I don't really understand　`100% accuracy`. Does it mean "the prometheus's monitoring data is not accurate"?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Prometheus prefers reliability over 100% accuracy, so there are tradeoffs where a tiny amount of data may be lost rather than taking out the whole system. This is fine for monitoring, but rarely okay when money is involved.

See also https://www.robustperception.io/monitoring-without-consensus/

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I understand the meaning of ``accuracy``.